# Data Dump - Posts.xml -- 'score'

Tags: support, data-dump, score

Browsing through the data dump, I have found a column named 'score'. From what I can tell it is simply restricted to being an integer value. My guess is that it's the sum of upvotes - downvotes, however I'd like to be sure.

What exactly is it, and if possible, how is it calculated (if not already obvious)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `score = upvotes - downvotes`. I don't know why the individual upvote and downvote counts aren't included, but you may be able to reconstruct them from the `votes` table if you need to.

Comment: I believe that the `score` is only being denormalized because that is what is showed in any given page. Upvotes and downvotes are only relevant when "auditing".